# How to have seedable RNG in parallel in rust

Tags: rust, raytracing, rayon

I am learning rust by implementing a raytracer. I have a working prototype that is single threaded and I am trying to make it multithreaded.

In my code, I have a sampler which is basically a wrapper around `StdRng::seed_from_u64(123)` (this will change when I will add different types of samplers) that is mutable because of `StdRNG`. I need to have a repeatable behaviour that is why i am seeding the random number generator.

In my rendering loop I use the sampler in the following way

```
        let mut sampler = create_sampler(&self.sampler_value);
        let sample_count = sampler.sample_count();

        println!("Rendering ...");
        let progress_bar = get_progress_bar(image.size());

        // Generate multiple rays for each pixel in the image
        for y in 0..image.size_y {
            for x in 0..image.size_x {
                image[(x, y)] = (0..sample_count)
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|_| {
                        let pixel = Vec2::new(x as f32, y as f32) + sampler.next2f();
                        let ray = self.camera.generate_ray(&pixel);
                        self.integrator.li(self, &mut sampler, &ray)
                    })
                    .sum::<Vec3>()
                    / (sample_count as f32);

                progress_bar.inc(1);
            }
        }
```

When I replace `into_iter` by `par_into_iter` the compiler tells me **cannot borrow `sampler` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure**

What should I do in this situation?

P.s. If it is of any use, this is the repo : https://github.com/jgsimard/rustrt

Comment: If you keep a **single** RNG for all the threads, you will kill the parallelism, whatever the locking/atomic mechanism used behind the scene, because you will have cache invalidations at each iteration of every thread. You probably need to parallelise with a handmade solution: choose explicitly the number of threads, divide equally your image along y by this number (something like `chunks_mut()`), provide each thread with its **own** RNG (seeded as you wish), and let these threads work **independently** on their partial slice of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Even if Rust wasn't stopping you, **you cannot just use a seeded PRNG with parallelism and get a reproducible result out.**

Think about it this way: a PRNG with a certain seed/state produces a certain *sequence of numbers*. Reproducibility (determinism) requires not just that the numbers are the same, but that *the way they are taken from the sequence is the same.* But if you have multiple threads computing different pixels (different uses) which are racing with each other to fetch numbers from the single PRNG, then the pixels will fetch different numbers on different runs.

In order to get the determinism you want, you must deterministically choose which random number is used for which purpose.

One way to do this would be to make up an “image” of random numbers, computed sequentially, and pass that to the parallel loop. Then each ray has its own random number, which it can use as its seed for *another* PRNG that only that ray uses.

Another way that can be much more efficient and usable (because it doesn't require any sequentiality at all) is to use hash functions instead of PRNGs. Whenever you want a random number, use a hash function (like those which implement the `std::hash::Hasher` trait in Rust, but not necessarily the particular one `std` provides since it's not the fastest) to combine a bunch of information, like

- the seed value
- the pixel x and y location
- which bounce or secondary ray of this pixel you're computing

into a single value which you can use as a pseudorandom number. This way, the “random” results are the same for the same circumstances (because you explicitly specfied that it should be computed from them) *even if some other part of the program execution changes* (whether that's a code change or a thread scheduling decision by the OS).

Comment: It is possible to use seedable PRNG in parallel in rust : https://rust-random.github.io/book/guide-parallel.html

Comment: @BobParker Yes, it is _possible._ When I said ‘make up an “image” of random numbers’, I meant what that page calls option 3. The options 1 and 2 do not give determinism.

Answer (score 0):

Your sampler is not thread-safe, if only because it is a `&mut Sampler` and mutable references cannot be shared between threads, obviously.

The easy thing would be to wrap it into an `Arc<Mutex<Sampler>>` and clone it to every closure. Something like (untested):

```
let sampler = Arc::new(Mutex::new(create_sampler(&self.sampler_value)));
//...
for y in 0..image.size_y {
            for x in 0..image.size_x {
                image[(x, y)] = (0..sample_count)
                    .par_into_iter()
                    .map({
                       let sampler = Arc::clone(sampler);
                       move |_| {
                           let mut sampler = sampler.lock().unwrap();
                           // use the sampler
                       }
                    })
                    .sum::<Vec3>() //...
```

But that may not be very efficient way because the mutex will be locked most of the time, and you will kill the paralellism. You may try locking/unlocking the mutex during the ray tracing and see if it improves.

The ideal solution would be to make the `Sampler` thread-safe and inner mutable, so that the `next2f` and friends do not need the `&mut self` part (`Sampler::next2f(&self)`). Again, the easiest way is having an internal mutex.

Or you can try going lock-less! I mean, your current implementation of that function is:

```
    fn next2f(&mut self) -> Vec2 {
        self.current_dimension += 2;
        Vec2::new(self.rng.gen(), self.rng.gen())
    }
```

You could replace the `current_dimension` with an `AtomicI32` and the `rng` with a `rand::thread_rng` (also untested):

```
    fn next2f(&self) -> Vec2 {
        self.current_dimension.fetch_add(2, Ordering::SeqCst);
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        Vec2::new(rng.gen(), rng.gen())
    }
```

Comment: Using the atomic version, I dont see how I can still seed the random number generator

Comment: (if you want to test it, ```cargo run --release -- -o test.png -s 3```)

Comment: My idea was to use the atomic for the counter and the `rand::thread_rng()` for the random number generator, that is a static, thread-local RNG, so you do not seed it, it already exists. If you still want to seed it, you can create your own thread-local, but then it each thread will have its own, and the concurrency will make it unpredictable anyway (that is, your output will not be reproducible).

Comment: If you really want reproducible outputs, then you have to be very, very careful mixing the RNG and the threading.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it. I used this ressource : rust-random.github.io/book/guide-parallel.html. So I used `ChaCha8Rng`  with the `set_stream` function to get seedable PRNG in parallel. I had to put the `image[(x, y)]` outside of the iterator because `into_par_iter` does not allow mutable borrow inside a closure. If you see something dumb in my solution, please tell me!

```
let size_x = image.size_x;
let img: Vec<Vec<Vec3>> = (0..image.size_y)
    .into_par_iter()
    .map(|y| {
         (0..image.size_x)
             .into_par_iter()
             .map(|x| {
                 let mut rng = ChaCha8Rng::seed_from_u64(sampler.seed());
                 rng.set_stream((y * size_x + x) as u64);
                 let v = (0..sample_count)
                     .into_iter()
                     .map(|_| {
                         let pixel = Vec2::new(x as f32, y as f32) + sampler.next2f(&mut rng);
                         let ray = self.camera.generate_ray(&pixel);
                         self.integrator.li(self, &sampler, &mut rng, &ray)
                     })
                     .sum::<Vec3>()
                     / (sample_count as f32);
                  progress_bar.inc(1);
                  v
              }).collect()
      }).collect();

for (y, row) in img.into_iter().enumerate() {
    for (x, p) in row.into_iter().enumerate() {
         image[(x, y)] = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rust Rand Book has a [whole chapter dedicated to random generators and parallelism](https://rust-random.github.io/book/guide-parallel.html).

> Use a single master seed. For each work unit, seed an RNG using the master seed and set the RNG's stream to the work unit number.

Note that this is not supported by all RNGs.

Here the example they gave that is fully deterministic:

```rust
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform};
use rand_chacha::{rand_core::SeedableRng, ChaCha8Rng};
use rayon::prelude::*;

static SEED: u64 = 0;
static BATCH_SIZE: u64 = 10_000;
static BATCHES: u64 = 1000;

fn main() {
    let range = Uniform::new(-1.0f64, 1.0);

    let in_circle = (0..BATCHES)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| {
            let mut rng = ChaCha8Rng::seed_from_u64(SEED);
            rng.set_stream(i);
            let mut count = 0;
            for _ in 0..BATCH_SIZE {
                let a = range.sample(&mut rng);
                let b = range.sample(&mut rng);
                if a * a + b * b <= 1.0 {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            count
        })
        .reduce(|| 0usize, |a, b| a + b);

    // prints 3.1409052 (determinstic and reproducible result)
    println!(
        "π is approximately {}",
        4. * (in_circle as f64) / ((BATCH_SIZE * BATCHES) as f64)
    );
}
```